# Viewing the palindrome of the word I Enter. After Confirming the word is Palindrome, I want to view the Palindrome Version of the word

Tags: c++, palindrome

I want to view the word after it been confirm as palindrome. But the output ended up in different way than what I expected. Pls help me Configure what is my error from my codes

Output I want to achieved:

Enter a word Madam

Word is Palendrome: madam

```
#include <iostream>       
#include <stack>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
string words;
cout<<"Enter a word ";
cin>>words;

int wordSize = words.size();
stack<char> mystack; 
for (int i=0; i<wordSize/2; ++i) {
mystack.push(tolower(words[0]));
words.erase(0,1);
}
if(words.size() > mystack.size()) {
words.erase(0, 1);
}
if(mystack.size() == 0) {
return true;
}
cout << "Popping out elements...";
while(!mystack.empty()) {
if(mystack.top() == words[0]) {
mystack.pop();
words.erase(0, 1);
if (mystack.size() == 0 || words.size() == 0) {
cout<<"Word is Palindrome: "<<<words<<endl;

return true;
}
}
else {
cout<<"Word is not Palindrome"<<endl;   
return false;
}
}
}
```

Comment: On, line number 30 you have an extra `<` remove it and you're good to go~

`cout<<"Word is Palindrome: "<<words<<endl;`

Comment: @YashKaranke
this is the output

    Enter a word Madam

    Popping out elements...Word is Palindrome:

this is the output when i run the program.. After confirming its a palindrome.. it will not show the palindrome version of the word.

Comment: Yup..It's working now check [here](http://cpp.sh/4fcey) . Just remove that extra `<` in line 30 as per my initial comment.

Comment: @YashKaranke the output is incomplete because i want to show the word madam after its confirmed Palindrome like this >>>>>>**Enter a word Madam Popping out elements... Word is Palindrome: madam**

Comment: If you wanted to keep the original word, why do you explicitly erase it? Just cache a copy at the beginning and display that.